# The future of Web Design & Front-end Development?

Tags: user-interface, frontend, user-experience, material-design

I am a little bit confused about the future of my job (front end web developer & designer).

I always learn the latest technologies to do my work. But i am anxious about losing my job in the future, Cuz everyday a new "Website Builder & Create your own website "website or application came up.

Despite of thinking part is getting harder (User Experience), Design part is being simplier (flat design, material design) day by day.

Do you think that "Web Design & Front-end Development" will transform to another job field? 
or what should we learn to be able to do our job in the future?

Comment: Tools and technologies come and go.
Principles and practices are here to stay.
Focus on priciples and practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing something that is common across all of software development: whatever you learn today will not be the hottest thing in the future.  You've also identified an important point here: the thinking part is getting harder.

The thinking part is what sets apart a good developer from a great developer.  A good developer can learn the current hotness and deploy it.  A great developer can take a difficult problem and come up with solutions that meet the need, are scalable, and are well-written and well-documented so that someone else can come along in the future and update them to solve future needs.

Being able to show how you handled a difficult problem, the trade-offs that you made, what you delivered, and how you would make improvements on it, and what you might do differently if you know now what you didn't know then, are how you set yourself apart from your fellow web developers.  Another way to set yourself apart is to know the differences between the various technologies that you could use, and be able to articulate why you might choose one over the other.  It's very rare that a new technology perfectly replaces an existing technology.  That shows a knowledge of technologies, the flexibility to learn new technologies, and the ability to consider the strengths and weaknesses of each one and determine how that impacts what you need to develop.

It's quite possible that web development will become something else, or that you will decide to do something else.  Development has changed significantly, and it seems likely that it will continue to do so.  Likewise, as you continue in your career, you might find that you want to pursue something else (perhaps a different type of development, perhaps something technical but not development, perhaps something else entirely).  The transferrable skills that you can learn as a web developer are problem-solving, flexibility and adaptability, working in teams, and articulating how you have approached a problem and why you chose a particular method of handling the problem.